# I do not remember how to use the /* in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a bit of a problem. I don't remember how to use the `/*` in JavaScript like after the URL

example.

```
if(URL == "www.thing.com/"){}
```

So I don't remember were to place the `/*` to make it so it's not just `"www.thing.com"` but every other thing that comes after that, for example `"www.thing.com/questions/..."`.

Would it just be `"www.thing.com/*"`?

Comment: No such operator exists.  Learn about regular expressions.  (or the properties in `location`)

Comment: You don't remember? If you've seen `/*` in JS before it would've been the start of a block comment, not as a string wildcard: `/* this is a comment */`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` in a string doesn't do magic.

You can use `String.prototype.indexOf`:

```
var URL = "www.thing.com/foo/bar";
if(URL.indexOf("www.thing.com/") === 0){ /* this is executed */ }
```

or, if you want a more flexible wildcard, use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp like this `/^www\.thing\.com\/.*/`